# Node doesnt remove ETAG header

Tags: node.js, express

I try to remove etag from node headers but it keeps showing up.
I try to remove etag from node headers but it keeps showing up.

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.disable("etag");

app.get("/response001", (req, res) => {
  res.on("finish", () => {
    console.log(`request url = ${req.originalUrl}`);
    console.log(res.getHeaders());
  });
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "response.js"));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  debug("running server on port " + chalk.green("4000"));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express with version 4.x, the way to remove (disable) default setting values will be like `app.disable('setting_name')` - [Doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.disable)

For your case, you have to use `app.disable('etag');` instead of `app.set("etag", false);`

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Did you restart your server?

Comment: @hoangdv `app.disable('smth')` is literally just `app.set('smth', false)`

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Try change `/response` to `/response001` and try again, I just test on my side, it still working fine.

Comment: Still nothing. Iam updating the question with the server config

Comment: @GeorgePaouris ohh, this is an error of express 4.x , you can wait for 5.x version, https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2936 https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2294

Comment: But is says that app.disable('etag') sets etag to false for sendfile. This is not the case here.

Comment: @GeorgePaouris You are using `sendFile` function.